# Copy & Paste controls in source view of ASPX pages: How to force VS not to touch my IDs?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

If I drag a control from the toolbox in Visual Studio (2008+SP1) into an ASPX page I get a proposal for an ID:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

That's nice and helps not to forget to assign an ID. Most of the time I rename the ID like:

```
<asp:Button ID="MySpecialButtonForSpecialTask1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Now I have a task 2 (3, 4, ..., n) and need a button "MySpecialButtonForSpecialTask2". So I copy and paste the first one with ID="MySpecialButtonForSpecialTask1". That's the result:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

That's not nice since I need to change now "Button1" to "MySpecialButtonForSpecialTask2" but I would prefer to change "MySpecialButtonForSpecialTask1" to "MySpecialButtonForSpecialTask2".

Is there any setting or trick in VS to prevent assigning new IDs after copy and paste?

**Update**

I'm not looking for the option

"Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML> Miscellaneous > Auto ID elements on paste in Source view"

since it also turns off creating IDs for controls inserted from the toolbox. I only would like to switch off this when **copy & paste**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML> Miscellaneous > Auto ID elements on paste in Source view.  Uncheck the box to turn this feature off.

Comment: Found at http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/08/27/visual-studio-paste-without-changing-ids-in-source-view.aspx via google.

Comment: Came to post the same thing. Had to turn this off myself not too long ago.

Comment: Yes, I know this option. BUT: It does not only turn off the auto ID feature when copy and paste but also when you insert a new control from the toolbox so that the inserted control doesn't have any ID at all. I only dislike the copy & paste auto ID, creating an ID for a new inserted control is fine. Is there such a refined option?

Comment: Brian's comment above me answers the question finally.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when I need to copy a block of aspx code and just change the name of the controls I use Notepad as an intermediary.

For example:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFoo" runat="server" Text="Enter Foo:" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFoo" runat="server" />
```

If I wanted to copy these controls and change "Foo" to "Bar", I would copy the above into Notepad, Ctrl-H to replace "Foo" with "Bar", then paste the results into Visual Studio.

This tends to be quite handy when dealing with a large number of controls.